# Setting an initial value in an text field in redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, default-value, redux-form

i want to create an input text field like the image above and i'm using redux form. My code for the input field component is the following:

```
<input
      {...props.input}
      type={props.type}
      className="form-control input-box__input"
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
    />
```

[image]

In the Field tag my code is:

```
                <Field
                  id="currentPassword"
                  name="currentPassword"
                  component={inputField}
                  type="text"
                  disabled
                  value={userSettings.map(i => i.currentPassword)}
                />
```

Also in my container i use initialValues like this:

```
initialValues: fromJS({
      currentPassword: ownProps.currentPassword,
```

But it does not seem to work. Do you know why?

Comment: When you are creating the redux-form reducer and using it in combineReducers, are you importing from `redux-form` or `redux-form/immutable`?

Comment: redux-form/immutable :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the value prop of your `Field` component?  [redux-form docs[(http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/) don't list it as a valid prop for Field. Could you try removing it?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

you should use initialValues like for example:

```
const Wrapper = (props) => {
 class Login extends Component {
   ...
 }
 const LoginForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm',
  initialValues: {
    currentPassword: "initial currentPassword",
  },
 })(Login);
 return <LoginForm {...props} />;
}
```

or

```
<LoginForm
 initialValues={initialValues}
/>
```

http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/